# Angular2 how to create Promise that's executing Observable inside?

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-services, angular-promise

I think this isn't very complex problem, but I'm a little confused how to use Promise to this.

There are 3 important instances:

- Component
- HtppService
- ToolService

The structure is as follows: Component has ToolService to execute functions - for example function create(). 
ToolService has HttpService, and the method create() looks like this:

```
public create(){

  this.httpService.create().subscribe(

    (data) => {
      //some complex processing
    },
    (error) => {
      //handling error
    }
  );

}
```

As you can guess the `httpService.create()` returns `http.put()`

The problem is I want to inform `Component` about the result of `create()`. So my idea was that `create()` should return a Promise, which will be fulfilled when `(data)`, and rejected when `(error)`.

I'm a bit confused how to do this. Maybe I should do this in other way?
Please suggest something.

Comment: Subscribe listener should be in Component only. Directly call httpService.create() from Component instead of calling from ToolService.

Comment: @Srigar I don't want to do that. I want to process the response inside ToolService, not in component

Comment: Pass function reference as a parameter to ToolsService from component and subscribe it. It will work

Comment: this isn't what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Inside Your service `import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

in Your service constructor create instance of Http `constructor(private http:Http){}`

```
public create(parameterToBeSend : any){
  return 
  this.http.put(`http://enter_your_service_url_here`,parameterToBeSend)
  .map( (response: Response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
   })
  .catch( (error: Response) => {
      return Observable.throw('Something went wrong');  
   }) 
  }
```

`.map` will create another observable object and before sending data to your component you can simply process it here.
`.catch` if you want to send any customize error then this will be usefull, but make sure that it doen not return an Observable, so to you need to convert it explicitly as i did.
Lastly in your component use following

```
public create(){
this.httpService.create().subscribe(
 (data) => {//complex process},
 (error) => {//handling error}
);
}
```

Comment: do you want to create custom Observable or Promise?

Comment: It's no difference for me, I only want to extract the complex processing to service

Answer (score 0):

Your "Toolservice" should be like below

```
create(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpService.create().map((response) => {
      return response;
   });
 }
```

And "Component" should be like this

```
this.toolService.create().subscribe((response) => {
   // Do what ever you want here
});
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: well I know that this could work, but I'm looking for something else. I really want to return an observable or promise in create(), as you did, but I want to create this inside subscribe, not only map response and pass further

Comment: You can't return an observable from subscribe but if you use map instead of subscribe then an Observable is returned.